# Python/Tkinter App run on Raspberry Pi boot

Tags: python, linux, tkinter, raspberry-pi3, boot

I have created a python app with a GUI made with Tkinter on a Raspberry Pi 3.  I am currently trying to set up the Pi so that it runs my program on boot.  I don't need anything like the desktop or such to load unless my program crashes.

I have tried looking for ways to accomplish this such as [this post from the Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/57128/how-to-boot-into-own-python-script-gui-only) but haven't been able to get anything to work.  In fact when I tried out the suggestions in that link I hit a snag that made me have to reinstall Raspbian.  I am wondering if anyone over here knows how to get this working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may not need the desktop, but tkinter does. So you can't disable the graphical boot.

First, make your python file executable with this command:

```
chmod +x my_program.py
```

Then add a shebang to the top of the file. For python2, the first line of the file must be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Now you can launch your python program like any other program, including adding it to autostart. When I did this I just run the command

```
nano /home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
```

to start the nano text editor and add the line

```
@/home/pi/folder/my_program.py
```

to the end.

Comment: Thank you very much.  It is now working as intended.

Comment: @Novel yes, it works but after close my program, I can't see my dashboard. there is an only blank screen. what to do to move on my raspberry pi window.

Comment: @RishabhJhalani I don't thing that has anything to do with this startup command.

Comment: @Novel I got the solution for it, once look at here. http://pythonchoice.com/execute-script-at-startup-on-the-raspberry-pi/